# no modifications in XML file after running python code

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I wrote a code that must modify some values in a xml file. it looks to be working, but when i open this xml file threw PyCharm where i have added the modified file, it just doesn't change a thing. If anyone gave a respond to such a question, please point me where is it. Here is the code as well as the xml.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("farms.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root.findall('farm'):
    elem.set('money', '2000')
    money = elem.get('money')
    print(money)
```

xml

```
<farms>
  <farm farmId="1" name="Моя ферма" color="1" loan="0.000000" money="213" loanAnnualInterestRate="304.166656">
  <players>
  </players>       
 </farm>
</farms>
```

Comment: You don’t appear to have included any code that’s writing changes back to the file in the file system - can you elaborate on how you came to the conclusion that the code provided here should function otherwise?

Comment: i thought that the **set** function would change in the **elem** the string with **money**  to 2000. IDK why the ` isnt working

Comment: it is my first experience working with xml, could you tell me how should i do it otherwise?

Answer (score 1):

What you are missing is writing the `tree` back to disk.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("farms.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
for elem in root.findall('farm'):
    elem.set('money', '2000')
with open('new_farms.xml', 'wb') as f:
    tree.write(f)
```

Comment: it does work, but the problem is i do not need to create a new file, can you help me replace the information in this one?

Comment: sure. just change `open('new_farms.xml', 'wb')` to `open('farms.xml', 'wb')`

Comment: @JustStarted Glad I managed to help. Feel free to up vote.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.
Additionally,

```
print(xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(root))
```

will show what you expect.

Comment: where shoul i add it. here is the V2 of the code.```import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def main(char):
    tree = ET.parse("farms.xml")
    root = tree.getroot()
    for elem in root.findall('farm'):
        elem.set('money', '2000')
        money = elem.get(str(char))
    print(xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(root))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    char = eval(input("ammount to be set "))
    main(char)```

Comment: oh, i am sorry for that, hopefully you will get the idea

Comment: it still doesn t work for me, what does it change for you and what is the setup you are working in